# Нахождение наибольшего числа в массиве целых чисел

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Здравствуйте, помогите найти ошибку! Нужно написать на C функцию нахождения наибольшего числа в массиве целых чисел:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_largest_number(int* array, unsigned int SIZE)
{
    int i;
    int max = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++) 
    {
        if(array[i] > max)
        {
        max = array[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}

int main ()
{
    int *array;
    unsigned int SIZE;
    printf("\nEnter size of array: ");
    scanf ("%d", &SIZE);
    int i;
    printf("\nEnter %d elements: \n\n", SIZE);
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("The largest number: ", get_largest_number(array, SIZE));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Вы ведь не ждёте, что кто-то за вас напишет код. Спрашивайте, мы попробуем ответить.

Comment: А так, у вас условие окончания цикла неправильное. И начальное значение должно быть не нулём, а минимальным `int`’ом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы же почти написали :)

Давайте только исправим несколько ошибок. Во-первых, если вы выделяете память для массива размером `SIZE`, то нужно и записывать `SIZE` элементов, а не `SIZE+1` - т.е. исправьте

```
for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
```

на

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
```

Раз вы выделили память, по окончании работы ее стоит освободить - доавьте перед `return 0;` еще `free(array)`.

Чтобы число выводилось - нужно добавить `%d`:

```
printf("The largest number: %d\n"
```

В самой функции - опять же, у вас *только* `SIZE` элементов - надо исправить цикл. Ну и - а вдруг все элементы будут меньше нуля? Тогда значение 0 в качестве начального бессмысленно. Возьмите в качестве `max` значение *первого* элемента массива, и начинайте сравнение *со второго*.

Итак, вот окончательный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_largest_number(int* array, unsigned int SIZE)
{
    int i;
    int max = array[0];
    for(i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > max)
        {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}

int main ()
{
    int *array;
    unsigned int SIZE;
    printf("\nEnter size of array: ");
    scanf ("%d", &SIZE);
    int i;
    printf("\nEnter %d elements: \n\n", SIZE);
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("The largest number: %d\n", get_largest_number(array, SIZE));
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в массиве все числа отрицательные, то оператором

```
max = 0;
```

Вы автоматически присваиваете число, больше любого элемента массива. Лучше присваивать значение первого элемента массива

Далее, у Вас цикл

```
for(i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
```

но если в массиве `SIZE` элементов, то последний элемент имеет индекс `SIZE - 1` и цикл должен быть

```
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
```

в итоге функция примет такой вид

```
int get_largest_number(int* array, unsigned int SIZE) {
    if (SIZE <= 0)
      // что-то вернуть, если элементов нет
    int max = array[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if(array[i] > max)
          max = array[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Или можно присвоить минимальное возможное значение для указанного типа данных

```
max = MIN_INT;
```

Comment: Гляньте на свой код и скажите, что вернет функция, если первый же элемент будет максимальным? :)

Comment: @Harry  второй максимальный, если максимальный не встретится еще раз :)